# Error occured while export data from excel

Tags: export-to-excel

I am getting an error while exporting data to an excel sheet.

#### Code

```
Response.Clear()
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition",   "attachment;filename=CompletionDatesReport.xls")
Response.Charset = ""
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache)
Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.xls"
Dim stringWrite As StringWriter = New StringWriter()
Dim htmlWrite As HtmlTextWriter = New HtmlTextWriter(stringWrite)
gridData.RenderControl(htmlWrite)
Response.Write(stringWrite.ToString())
Response.End()
```

#### Error

> Internet explorer cannot download abc.aspx from www.xyz.com.
>   Internet explorer was not able to open this internet site.The requested site is either unavailable or cannot be found.Please try again later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the line no 4

Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache)

It will be work.

Comment: Thanks! Its working fine now.I did two task. 1).Remove the line no. 4 2).Add Response.clearheaders() after Response.Clear() But i didn't reason why it was giving error before doing these modification.